# libGDX : Drawable from Image can't change its color

Tags: java, colors, libgdx

When I get `Drawable` from `Image` from one white pixel (1×1) `Texture`, its work fine, but I can't change its color. Why?

```
public static Drawable getDrawable(Texture texture, Color color) {
    Image image = new Image(texture);
    image.setColor(color);
    return image.getDrawable();
}
```

When I call it:

```
// can't change color!! ==> still white (default)
getDrawable(pixel, new Color(0, 1f, 0, 0.5f));
```

Anyone Can advice me :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Drawable types that support having their own color are SpriteDrawable and NinePatchDrawable, and that is because they wrap Sprites and NinePatches, which both have color parameters.

```
public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(Texture texture, Color color) {
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setColor(color);
    return new SpriteDrawable(sprite);
}
```

If you have an existing TextureRegionDrawable or NinePatchDrawable, you can call `tint()` on it to generate a new Drawable instance with the color you want.

Comment: `SpriteDrawable` class which I am looking for. Thanks :)